# Dynamically Adding text boxes and storing its value in mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

This is my script to add the textboxes dynamically

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
       $('#myTable #row').append('<tr class="child"><td class="child" colspan="2"><input type="text"></td><td></td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;"><input type="text"></td></tr>');
    });
});
</script>
```

I am working with codeigniter.
I need to store dynamically entered textbox values into my table in the database and have to perform mathematical operations on those values.
Please do help me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try declaring input as array

Answer (score 0):

Your text box should have `name="my-name[]"`. (You can change "my-name" to something you want.)

On the controller side, you can do:

```
foreach($this->input->post('my-name') as $index => $value){
    // Do something with $value
}
```

Comment: Thank You sir, I will try with this